# Is there a way to to use the nav html code on every page without adding it to each html file? (keeping it DRY)

Tags: html

I usually use PHP where we have a header.php file and a footer.php. Which means you don't need to repeat the same blocks of code for each of these sections on your other pages.

I'm creating a site with just HTML that has a few pages, but I don't want to use the nav code on each of my html files.

Is there any way to achieve what I want with HTML?

Comment: With pure HTML, no. With an HTML preprocessor, templating engine or JS, sure there is.

Comment: Iframe would be pure html.

Answer (score 0):

I normally keep using php for this. Even if there is no php code, only the include. Else you need to use javascript for it: https://devdojo.com/tnylea/include-html-inside-of-html

But using php is the most easy and standard way. Why wouldn't you want to use php and only html?

**EDIT: You could use iframe for it by the way.**

Answer (score -1):

The way this is done when one wishes not to use `php` is by using an `iframe`. I have included an example for you below!

**iframe.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="nav justify-content-center|justify-content-end">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active link</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled link</a>
    </nav>

    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**home.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Iframe Nav Bar</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.0.2 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        iframe {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 20vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="iframe.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```